# how to detect if the gas stove is on when the stove is near the window

Tags: pi-3, sensor

My mother often forgot to turn off the gas stove, it is very dangerous, I am worry about it. So I want to make some thing to detect whether the gas stove is turned off or not. I bought a flame sensor, but the gas stove is near the window, it seems the sensor is made of infrared photodiode and can't separate light through the window and the flame.
The switch is range knob , you have to press the knob and rotate to turn on the stove. I think it is hard to put a magnet under it to use a reed switch.
Is there a way to check if the gas stove is on?

Comment: Why not use a temperature sensor instead, and compare the current temperature against the "normal" temperature?

Comment: Could you monitor the on switch for the heat?

Comment: What is the source of heat? An electric space heater? Some sort of fuel-burning space heater? Something else?

Comment: @jaolstad I was wondering if it is OK to put the sensor and raspberry pi in a high temperature and high humidity environment.

Comment: @bobstro It is gas stove with some range knobs as a switch, You have to press the knob and rotate to turn on the stove. I think it is hard to put a magnet under it to use a reed switch.

Comment: @larsks It is gas stove with some range knobs as a switch, You have to press the knob and rotate to turn on the stove. I think it is hard to put a magnet under it to use a reed switch.

Comment: Perhaps heat or flame sensors under the burners?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend a DS18B20 temperature sensor. They're available in smart little packages, very accurate and can be directly connected to the Pi's GPIO.

Cheap too! Example: https://www.amazon.co.uk/DS18b20-Waterproof-Temperature-Sensors-Transducer/dp/B00CHEZ250/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1515082943&sr=8-4&keywords=temperature+sensor

These use the 1-Wire interface to communicate, which is readily supported by Python, PHP etc. There's a great tutorial here: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-11-ds18b20-temperature-sensing/overview

I use one of these to monitor my aquarium's temperature. I get an alert if it goes out of range.

Then, all you need to do is workout the temperature changes when the heating comes on. You could either measure change over time or have upper and lower thresholds.

Comment: Thank you. I have one DS18B20, but just the small ic itself. I was wondering if it is OK to put the sensor and raspberry pi in a high temperature and high humidity environment.

Comment: Not if it's just the bare IC, no. The package version (see link above) is waterproof (mine lives in an aquarium). I think the plastic surround melting will be the highest temperature point. Suitably insulate the Pi in a good case and it should be fine.